# Cosets and order

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be a subgroups of a group $G$, of orders |H|=2 and |K|=5. Some cosets of H may contain elements of K. How many such cosets could there be ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint : 
1. If $gH$ is a coset such that $k \in K$ is in $gH$, then $gH = kH$. So the cosets you are looking for are 
$$
\{ kH : k\in K\}
$$
2. Now for counting them : For $k_1, k_2\in K$, $k_1 H = k_2 H$ iff $k_2^{-1}k_1 \in H$, which happens iff
$$
k_2^{-1}k_1 \in K\cap H
$$
What do you know about $K\cap H$?

Added : Conclude that the map
$$
K \mapsto G/H, \text{ given by } k \mapsto kH
$$
is a bijection between $K$ and the number of cosets which contain elements of $K$.

Comment: So there are 6 ?

Comment: How do you conclude that?

Comment: The order of H is 2 so H={x,y}. How I would like to find cosets of H such that there elements elevated to the fifth power give me 1 no ?

Comment: No! You just want cosets which contain an element of $K$. Their fifth power may or may not be 1, that is not relevant.

Comment: So how many are there ?

Comment: I have added what is essentially the answer.